# Error 1064 in MySQL forward engineering

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to MySQL and currently experimenting with MySQL workbench. I have been attempting to forward engineer a simple database schema from a model. Whenever I attempt to do this however it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'NOT NULL,
`tbl_Arti_id_Arti` INT NOT NULL,
`tbl_Usr_id_Usr` INT NOT NULL,
' at line 6
```

I understand that the syntax is wrong, however i was wondering if anyone could point me as to how to fix it.

---

EDIT:
Please find below the auto generated create statement:

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AstuteSchema`.`tbl_authorArti` (
      `id_usrArti` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `usrArti_IsPri` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
      `tbl_Arti_id_Arti` INT NOT NULL,
      `tbl_Usr_id_Usr` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_usrArti`),
      INDEX `fk_tbl_authorArti_tbl_Arti1_idx` (`tbl_Arti_id_Arti` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_tbl_authorArti_tbl_Usr1_idx` (`tbl_Usr_id_Usr` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_tbl_authorArti_tbl_Arti1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`tbl_Arti_id_Arti`)
        REFERENCES `AstuteSchema`.`tbl_Arti` (`id_Arti`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_tbl_authorArti_tbl_Usr1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`tbl_Usr_id_Usr`)
        REFERENCES `AstuteSchema`.`tbl_Usr` (`id_Usr`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the syntax is auto-generated by Workbench I don't think there's much you can do. In any case, you can check the context of that query and see if there's something strange in the column involved.

Comment: @OP: Post your *CREATE* statement. unless which it is hard to predict cause of error.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález please see above edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you the exact location:

```
`usrArti_IsPri` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                       ^
```

Apparently, your model does not set a size for `usrArti_IsPri` and the code generator does not care validating it.